# Facebook integration with xcode 4.2 and ios5

Tags: facebook, ios5, xcode4.2

I have created an Ipad app in ios 5 with ARC enabled. This will upload videos to facebook. When I have added facebook sdk to my project it gives me error related to ARC. I have also set flag as "-fno-objc-arc" (without double quotes) in compile sources under build phases in setting of the facebook project. But its still giving those errors.
How can i resolved those issues

Comment: The errors are
"release" is unavailable in automatic reference counting mode.

Existing ivar'_sessionDelegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'sessionDelegate' must be _unsage_unretained.

ARC forbids explicti message send of 'release' .

Cast of C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString') to Obejctive-C pointer type 'NSString *' requires a bridged cast.

Comment: which Facebook SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is Memory Management issue.In ARC "release" is unavailable.I think you release an object Which cause the app crash.

Comment: these issues are in facebook library not in my project files